# How can I open a file in c++, without erasing its contents and not append it?

Tags: c++, operating-system, filesystems, fstream, ifstream

I am trying to find a way using which I can Edit the contents in a binary file, without reading the whole file.

Suppose this is my file

```
abdde
```

And I want to make it

```
abcde
```

I tried following:-
Attempt 1)

```
ofstream f("binfile", ios::binary);
if(f.is_open()){
  char d[]={'c'};
  f.seekp(2,ios::beg);
  f.write(d, 1);
  f.close();
}
//the file get erased
```

Output:

```
**c
```

Attempt 2)

```
ofstream f("binfile", ios::binary | ios::app);
if(f.is_open()){
  char d[]={'c'};
  f.seekp(2,ios::beg);
  f.write(d, 1);
  f.close();
}
//the file simple gets append seekp() does nothing
```

Output:

```
abddec
```

Attempt 3)

```
ofstream f("binfile", ios::binary | ios::app);
if(f.is_open()){
  char d[]={'c'};
  f.seekp(2);
  f.write(d, 1);
  f.close();
}
//same as before the file simple gets append seekp() does nothing
```

Output:

```
abddec
```

And if I just try to replace the 1st byte of the file, which is 'a' with 'h'

```
ofstream f("binfile", ios::binary);
if(f.is_open()){
  char d[]={'c'};
  f.seekp(ios::beg);
  f.write(d, 1);
  f.close();
}
//file is erased
```

Output:

```
h
```

What do I do? Is it even possible for the OS to allow a program to edit a file at any point own its own?

Comment: The table in [this `filebuf::open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) might help. It tells me you should use `in|out` open-mode.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ios::app` means the cursor is put at the end of the file before every write. Seeking has no effect.

Meanwhile, `std::ios::binary` goes into "truncation" mode by default for an output stream.

You want neither of those.

I suggest `std::ios::out | std::ios::in`, perhaps by just creating a `std::fstream fs(path, std::ios::binary)` rather than using an `std::ofstream`.

Yes, it's a bit confusing.

*([Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open))*

Comment: Yes, fstream f(path", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out); works :-)