# Why is this binary file write cutting off the end of my file?

Tags: c++, file, struct, binary

So, what I've done is to create an array of structs.  I then write that array to a binary file.  I think seek to the second struct in the file and overwrite it.  I then read the file back into a separate array of structs and print it to the screen.

Once the write is complete, the file size goes from 24 bytes to 16 bytes, the first struct is corrupted and the last struct is lost from the file.

Here's my code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

void print(const Point& p)
{
    cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Point p[] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

    for(auto a : p)
        print(a);

    // write array p to file
    fstream f("points.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    if(f)
    {
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p), 3 * sizeof(Point));
        f.close();
    }

    // read second struct from file and print it to screen
    f.open("points.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(f)
    {
        Point p;
        f.seekg( 1 * sizeof(Point), ios::beg);
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(Point));
        f.close();
        print(p);
    }

    // change ios::out to ios::ate and it works fine...
    f.open("points.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    if(f)
    {
        Point p ={-1, -2};
        f.seekp(1 * sizeof(Point), ios::beg);
        // attempting to overwrite the second struct in the file 
        // shrinks the file from 24 bytes to 16, losing the last
        // struct in the file and causing the first struct to have
        // 0's in it's fields.
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(Point));
        f.close();
    }


    Point q[3];
    // read the file back into q and print q for testing.
    f.open("points.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(f)
    {
        // fails because the file is now only 16 bytes, instead of 24 
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(q), 3 * sizeof(Point));      
        f.close();

        for(auto a : q)
            print(a);
    }   
}
```

The annoying part is when I change ios::out to ios::ate, it works just fine.

Comment: Although (IIRC) the use of `ios::out` (and other flags) is *implementation-defined*, I think using `ios::out` *implicitly* adds `ios::trunc` and `seekp` is ignored. (Certainly true for the old `fopen` mode-flag "w".)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059486/560648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`binary|out` is the same as `binary|out|trunc`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

That is, your file is truncated by default when you use that flag combination.

- If you only want to append, you want `binary|out|app`.
- Otherwise, you want `binary|out|in`.

Yes, I know you're not reading. Yes, for the second option the file has to already exist. Yes, it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you open a file with `binary|out` and the file already exists it destroys the contents.